# How do I show simple uptime in tmux's status bar?

Tags: tmux

I want to show the uptime in the tmux status bar in the format `DD:HH:MM`, without any of the other cruft that the `uptime` command shows.

I've tried these:

```
#set -g status-left '#[fg=green]#H #[fg=black]•#[fg=green,bright]#(uptime|awk '{split(substr($0, index($0, "load")),a, ":"); print a[2]})'#[default]'
set -g status-right '#[fg=red,bg=default]#(uptime) #[fg=blue]%a%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Neither works as I want. I want just a straight uptime of `DD:HH:MM`, updated every 30 seconds with the normal statusbar update.

Answer (score 9):

Here you can use `awk` to parse the output of `uptime` to suit your needs like this:

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=red,bg=default]#(uptime | awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/,//') #[fg=blue]%a%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Normally `uptime` returns this type of output:

```
$ uptime
 15:30:24 up  1:59,  4 users,  load average: 2.39, 2.08, 2.12
```

By using `awk` we can get rid of everything around the uptime.

```
$ uptime | awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/,//'
2:47
```

You could also use `/proc/uptime` to get the actual seconds that the system has been up and then use `awk` or `perl` to convert the seconds to days, hours, minutes, etc.

```
$ awk '{printf("%d:%02d:%02d:%02d",($1/60/60/24),($1/60/60%24),($1/60%60),($1%60))}' /proc/uptime
0:02:49:55
```

This shows the seconds of uptime in DD:HH:MM:SS.

You could also show them using Perl:

```
$ cat /proc/uptime |  perl -ne '/(\d*)/ ; printf "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n",int($1/86400),int(($1%86400)/36003600)/60),$1%60' 
00:02:50:53
```

#### tmux quoting?

As @JasonwRyan mentioned in the comments, `tmux` can be notoriously difficult to quote the commands just right. Here's how you could quote the `awk` example that I provided above.

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=red,bg=default]#(uptime | awk \"{print \\$3}\"|sed \"s/,//\") #[fg=blue]%a%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

However it's probably easier to just put the commands in a shell script and call that from within the `tmux` config file:

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=red,bg=default]#(somecommand.bash) #[fg=blue]%a%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

#### References

- [Convert seconds to well format date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34017/convert-seconds-to-well-format-date)
- [Error in tmux's configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397127/error-in-tmuxs-configuration-file)

Comment: You're cutting the current time :) This should do it: `uptime| cut -d" " -f4-|cut -d, -f1`. It's not always DD:HH:MM though, at least on my system.

Comment: Once uptime is more than one day the `awk` fields will change...

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - thanks for the feedback. I completely missed that 8-).

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - I've modified my approach so that it deals with `uptime` using `awk` and `sed`. Your approach would work too. I've also adapted my answer to include a solution using `/proc/uptime` instead.

Comment: @jasonwryan - thanks for pointing that out. Do you see any issues with using `/proc/uptime` as I've described?

Comment: A day increase would break my version too.

Comment: No: that seems like a good approach (especially if it works internally).

Comment: @slm I can see at least one drawback with `/proc/uptime`, it's Linux only, at least none of my FreeBSD and SunOS boxes have it. Parsing `uptime`s output will probably not be any more portable, though.

Comment: I've tried several of these solutions, and they work on the command-line but they don't work in the tmux conf file, and that's where I need them to work. Sorry folks to rain on your parade.

Comment: @user205787 `tmux` is notoriously unforgiving of quotation marks in the statusbar: you can see the [FAQ on escaping them](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ) or just call the `awk` script from an external file...

Comment: Thanks jasonwryan, I've now got it working from a bash script, and its showing the correct uptime. Lovely job, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `uptime -p`:

```
#(uptime -p)
```

Sample output:

```
up 4 hours, 17 minutes
```

I know that's not exactly what you wanted but close