# Get total duration of video files in a directory

Tags: shell-script, video

I have a list of `.ts` files:

```
out1.ts ... out749.ts   out8159.ts  out8818.ts
```

How can I get the total duration (running time) of all these files?

Comment: @Hauke Laging i found this program "mediainfo"

Comment: These are media files, likely video.

Comment: Any media files(e.g: MP4, ASF & .264...) will have predefined standard header information, we can get the information from that file like resolution, frame rate, number of frames(GOP) & file length & duration of the media...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I have no `.ts` here (only `.mp4`) but this should work for all video files:
Use `ffprobe` (part of `ffmpeg`) to get the time in seconds, e.g:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration Inception.mp4
```

```
275.690000
```

So for all video files you could use a `for` loop and `awk` to calculate the total time in seconds:

```
for f in ./*.mp4
do ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration "$f"
done | awk '{sum += $1}; END{print sum}'
```

```
2735.38
```

To further process the output to convert the total to `DD:HH:MM:SS`, see the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34017/22142).

---

Another way is via `exiftool` which has an internal `ConvertDuration`:

```
exiftool -n -q -p '${Duration;our $sum;$_=ConvertDuration($sum+=$_)
                    }' ./*.mp4 | tail -n1
```

```
0:45:35
```

Comment: Very nice, hadn't seen that trick w/ `ffprobe` before.

Comment: Nice trick with `paste` and `bc`! much cleaner than with `awk` let's say.

Comment: @fduff. While `bc` will do arbitrary precision, one drawback is that `...| paste -sd+ - | bc` will either reach the line size limit in some `bc` implementations (for instance `seq 429 | paste -sd+ - | bc` fails with OpenSolaris `bc`) or have the potential of using up all the memory in others.

Comment: Can you do this (ffprobe method) with something like avconv? I can't find ffmpeg in my repos for Kubuntu 14.04 - so I don't have ffprobe either? I do have avprobe, but it doesn't like those arguments.

Comment: Thanks, the following (maybe unformatted) works `DUR=$(avprobe -loglevel quiet -show_format_entry duration "$1");
DUR=$(cut -d '.' -f 1 <<< "$DUR");
((DUR_MIN=DUR/60));
echo "${DUR_MIN}"` I truncated the fractional seconds to avoid processing a floating point value.

Comment: exiftool can also only print a single tag: `exiftool -MediaDuration -T -S -n *.mp4` will do the job without awk!

Comment: How to pipe the bc output have hours instead of seconds ?

Answer (score 6):

This uses `ffmpeg` and prints the time out in total seconds:

```
times=()
for f in *.ts; do
    _t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | head -n1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
    times+=("$_t")
done
echo "${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

Explanation:

`for f in *.ts; do` iterates each of the files that ends in ".ts"

`ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1` redirects output to stderr

`grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | head -n1 | tr ',' ' '` isolates the time

`awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'` Converts time to seconds

`times+=("$_t")` adds the seconds to an array

`echo "${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc` expands each of the arguments and replaces the spaces and pipes it to `bc` a common linux calculator

Comment: Nice! Also see [my version](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170985/20807) which is heavily based on your ideas.

Comment: Short and elegant solution

Comment: How to pipe bc to have hours instead of seconds?

Answer (score 5):

Streamlining [@jmunsch's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170968/20807), and using the `paste` I just learned from [@slm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170969/20807), you could end up with something like this:

```
for i in *.ts; do LC_ALL=C ffmpeg -i "$i" 2>&1 | \
awk -F: '/Duration:/{print $2*3600+$3*60+$4}'; done | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Just like jmunsch did, I'm using `ffmpeg` to print the duration, ignoring the error about a missing output file and instead searching the error output for the duration line. I invoke `ffmpeg` with all aspects of the locale forced to the standard C locale, so that I won't have to worry about localized output messages.

Next I'm using a single `awk` instead of his `grep | grep | head | tr | awk`. That `awk` invocation looks for the (hopefully unique) line containing `Duration:`. Using colon as a separator, that label is field 1, the hours are field 2, the minutes filed 3 and the seconds field 4. The trailing comma after the seconds doesn't seem to bother my `awk`, but if someone has problems there, he could include a `tr -d ,` in the pipeline between `ffmpeg` and `awk`.

Now comes the part from slm: I'm using `paste` to replace newlines with plus signs, but without affecting the trailing newline (contrary to the `tr \\n +` I had in [a previous version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/170985/1) of this answer). That gives the sum expression which can be fed to `bc`.

Inspired by slm's idea of using `date` to handle time-like formats, here is a version which does use it to format the resulting seconds as days, hours, minutes and seconds with fractional part:

```
TZ=UTC+0 date +'%j %T.%N' --date=@$(for i in *.ts; do LC_ALL=C \
ffmpeg -i "$i" 2>&1 | awk -F: '/Duration:/{print $2*3600+$3*60+$4}'; done \
| paste -sd+ | bc) | awk '{print $1-1 "d",$2}' | sed 's/[.0]*$//'
```

The part inside `$(…)` is exactly as before. Using the `@` character as an indication, we use this as the number of seconds since the 1 January 1970. The resulting “date” gets formatted as day of the year, time and nanoseconds. From that day of the year we subtract one, since an input of zero seconds already leads to day 1 of that year 1970. I don't think there is a way to get day of the year counts starting at zero.

The final `sed` gets rid of extra trailing zeros. The `TZ` setting should hopefully force the use of UTC, so that daylight saving time won't interfere with *really* large video collections. If you have more than one year worth of video, this approach still won't work, though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the `.ts` extension, but assuming they're some type of video file you can use `ffmpeg` to identify the duration of a file like so:

```
$ ffmpeg -i some.mp4 2>&1 | grep Dura
  Duration: 00:23:17.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 504 kb/s
```

We can then split this output up, selecting just the duration time.

```
$ ffmpeg -i some.mp4 2>&1 | grep -oP "(?<=Duration: ).*(?=, start.*)"
00:23:17.01
```

So now we just need a way to iterate through our files and collect these duration values.

```
$ for i in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" 2>&1 | grep -oP "(?<=Duration: ).*(?=, start.*)"; done
00:23:17.01
00:23:17.01
00:23:17.01
```

**NOTE:** Here for my example I simply copied my sample file `some.mp4` and named it `1.mp4`, `2.mp4`, and `3.mp4`.

#### Converting times to seconds

The following snippet will take the durations from above and convert them to seconds.

```
$ for i in *.mp4; do 
    dur=$(ffmpeg -i "$i" 2>&1 | grep -oP "(?<=Duration: ).*(?=, start.*)");
    date -ud "1970/01/01 $dur" +%s; done
1397
1397
1397
```

This takes our durations and puts them in a variable, `$dur`, as we loop through the files. The `date` command is then used to calculate the number of seconds sine the Unix epoch (1970/01/01). Here's the above `date` command broken out so it's easier to see:

```
$ date -ud "1970/01/01 00:23:17.01" +%s
1397
```

**NOTE:** Using `date` in this manner will only work if all your files have a duration that's < 24 hours (i.e. 86400 seconds). If you need something that can handle larger durations you can use this as an alternative:

```
sed 's/^/((/; s/:/)*60+/g' | bc
```

*Example*

```
$ echo 44:29:36.01 | sed 's/^/((/; s/:/)*60+/g' | bc
160176.01
```

#### Totaling up the times

We can then take the output of our `for` loop and run it into a `paste` command which will incorporate `+` signs in between each number, like so:

```
$ for i in *.mp4; do 
    dur=$(ffmpeg -i "$i" 2>&1 | grep -oP "(?<=Duration: ).*(?=, start.*)");
    date -ud "1970/01/01 $dur" +%s; done | paste -s -d+
1397+1397+1397
```

Finally we run this into the command line calculator, `bc` to sum them up:

```
$ for i in *.mp4; do 
    dur=$(ffmpeg -i "$i" 2>&1 | grep -oP "(?<=Duration: ).*(?=, start.*)");
    date -ud "1970/01/01 $dur" +%s; done | paste -s -d+ | bc
4191
```

Resulting in the total duration of all the files, in seconds. This can of course be converted to some other format if needed.

Comment: @DamenSalvatore - no problem, hopefully it shows you how you can break the task down into various steps, so you can customize it as needed.

Comment: @slm - I would use another way to convert the video duration to seconds as `date` might choke if `ffmpeg -i some.mp4 2>&1 | grep -oP "(?<=Duration: ).*(?=, start.*)"` returns something like `26:33:21.68` (that is, duration ≥ 24 hours/86400 seconds)

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks, I hadn't tried it beyond 20 hours when testing it out. I'll add a note showing an alternative method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Not only did it inspire [mine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170985/20807), but it also brought `paste` to my attention. I guess `java -classpath $(find -name \*.jar | paste -sd:)` is going to be *very* useful to me, considering the hacks I'd used for this in the past.

Comment: @MvG - `paste` is my favorite command 8-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, these all solution need a bit of work, what I did was very simple,
1)

1. went to the desired folder and right click -> open with other
   application
2. Then select VLC media player,
3. this will start playing one of the videos, **but then**
4. press ***ctrl + L***, and you will see the playlist of the videos and somewhere on top left corner you will see total duration

here is example

1.
[image: List item]

2.[image]

3.[image]

You can see just under the toolbar, there is **Playlist[10:35:51]** written,
so folder contains 10 hours 35 mins and 51 sec duration of total videos

Answer (score 1):

Going off the accepted answer and using the classic UNIX reverse-polish tool:

```
{ find . -maxdepth 2 -iname '*.mp4' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 \
         -show_entries format=duration {} \; ; printf '+\n60\n*\np'; } | dc
```

> 783.493000

I.e.: Appening `+` and `p` then piping that into [`dc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)) and you'll get your sum.

Comment: [`bc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) gets way too much love. You're all putting `+` signs between each line (joining on `+`), whereas with reverse-polish you can just chuck a `+` on the end and `p`rint it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find -iname '*.ts' -print0 |\
xargs -0  mplayer -vo dummy -ao dummy -identify 2>/dev/null |\
perl -nle '/ID_LENGTH=([0-9\.]+)/ && ($t += $1) && printf "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$t/86400,$t/3600%24,$t/60%60,$t%60'
```

Be sure that you have **MPlayer** installed.

Comment: it doesnt give me any output

Comment: do you have mplayer and perl installed?

Comment: yes i installed mplayer and perl was already installed

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it's not working; but, you already have enough decent answers already anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

As ubuntu ship libav instead of ffmpeg :

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.mp4; do
    avprobe -v quiet -show_format_entry duration "$f"
done | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Heavily based on [MvG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170961/get-total-duration-of-video-files-in-a-directory/170985#170985) ideas

Answer (score 0):

I had sub-directories on the current folder so I had to recursively compute the duration:

`find . -iname '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs --null exiftool -n -q -p  '${Duration;our $sum;$_=ConvertDuration($sum+=$_)}' | tail -n1`

Answer (score 0):

For music collections I use [Banshee](https://banshee.fm) [[`AUR`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/banshee)].

[image]